# Separate semicolon separated values in Pandas Data Frame

Tags: python, pandas, list, dataframe, sorting

I am using Pandas to separate the semicolon separated values in a column. But there are more or less values in each row. For example:

```
row1: SVANN=TANDEM; SVTYPE=DEL; SVLENGTH=500

row2: IMPRECISE; SVANN=TANDEM; SV TYPE=INS; SVLENGTH= 300
```

How to separate these semicolon values into separate coulmns.

I tried the following steps but the values are misplaced:

```
df_checknew = pd.read_excel("annotated.xlsx")
df_checknew['INFO'] = df_checknew['INFO'].str.split(';')
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_checknew['INFO'].tolist()).fillna('')
df = pd.concat([df_checknew, df_new], axis=1)
```

INFO is the column with many semicolon separated values. df_new has column names 0, 1,2 and 3 and the values are misplaced in each column. In df the column names are missing

Example:

[image]##input

[image] ## values are misplaced because of the variable fish
[image] ##output

Thanks

Comment: Is your datafile an excel file or text file? Provide a sample of the input dataframe and expected output.

Comment: I have provided snapshot of the files in the question above. Thanks

Comment: It is hard to understand the transformation logic here, because the columns are not aligned. Please simplify this with a minimal example.

Comment: You have two variaents one separated by colon `:` and other one separated by `=` as  `SVLENGTH=500` in the first row. Can you confirm if you have the right input data?

Comment: Sorry, I have edited in the question. There are variables with values, for example SVANN=TANDEM (not by colon)